# create single email alert in sharepoint designer 2010 detailing all new items added to a list in a day

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, designer

I want the workflow to create one email alert listing all new items added to a list in a day. With a link to each individual item.Not allowed to use visual studio, can use designer 2010

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right , then you need an email for all the items added in a list right?

Correct me if I am wrong.

If so then you can use the feature called as Alert which is available in Sharepoint OOTB.

Whch has the option to set the frequency of number of emails to send Like for each item or at the end of the day or at specific time.

read more about alerts hre :

https://answers.uchicago.edu/page.php?id=32689
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802949(v=office.14).aspx

Let me know if this helps you or not?